# merge two lists based on a condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-template

```
    "ansible_facts": {
        "list1": [
            "10",
            "2",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7",
            "7",
            "8",
            "9"
        ],
```

```
        "list2": [
            [
                "10",
                "xxxxx"
            ],
            [
                "2",
                "yyyyy"
            ],
            [
                "4",
                "zzzzz"
            ],
            [
                "5",
                "mmmmm"
            ],
            [
                "6",
                "fffff"
            ],
            [
                "7",
                "gggggg"
            ],
            [
                "8",
                "hhhhh"
            ],
            [
                "9",
                "kkkkkk"
            ]
```

Here I have two lists, I want to merge list2, just the words(xxxx,yyyy,...) with list1, but with condition that whenever the number on list2 match list1 then merge it to it's according number on list 1. But as you can see there can be some repeating number making it not perfectly aligned. When I sort the list like above still the the condition won't work when numbers repeat.

```
``
the condition that i've tried
    when: list1[item|int] == list2[item|int]
    with_sequence: start=0 end={{countvar.stdout|int - 1}}
```

Expected merged list
```

```
    "list3": [
        [
            "10",
            "xxxxx"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "yyyyy"
        ],
        [
            "4",
            "zzzzz"
        ],
        [
            "5",
            "mmmmm"
        ],
        [
            "6",
            "fffff"
        ],
        [
            "7",
            "gggggg"
        ],
        [
            "7",
            "gggggg"
        ],
        [
            "8",
            "hhhhh"
        ],
        [
            "9",
            "kkkkkk"
        ]
```

Comment: add the expected (merged) list to the question

Comment: I've added it to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the lists

```yaml
  l1: ['10', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7', '8', '9']
  l2:
    - ['10', xxxxx]
    - ['2', yyyyy]
    - ['4', zzzzz]
    - ['5', mmmmm]
    - ['6', fffff]
    - ['7', gggggg]
    - ['8', hhhhh]
    - ['9', kkkkkk]
```

---

1. Convert the second list to a dictionary

```yaml
  d2: "{{ dict(l2) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  d2:
    '10': xxxxx
    '2': yyyyy
    '4': zzzzz
    '5': mmmmm
    '6': fffff
    '7': gggggg
    '8': hhhhh
    '9': kkkkkk
```

2. Extract the values

```yaml
  v1: "{{ l1|map('extract', d2)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  v1: [xxxxx, yyyyy, zzzzz, mmmmm, fffff, gggggg, gggggg, hhhhh, kkkkkk]
```

3. zip the lists

```yaml
  l3: "{{ l1|zip(v1) }}"
```

gives what you're looking for

```yaml
  l3:
    - ['10', xxxxx]
    - ['2', yyyyy]
    - ['4', zzzzz]
    - ['5', mmmmm]
    - ['6', fffff]
    - ['7', gggggg]
    - ['7', gggggg]
    - ['8', hhhhh]
    - ['9', kkkkkk]
```

You can put it in one line which gives the same result

```yaml
  l3: "{{ l1|zip(l1|map('extract', dict(l2))|list) }}"
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    l1: ['10', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7', '8', '9']
    l2:
      - ['10', xxxxx]
      - ['2', yyyyy]
      - ['4', zzzzz]
      - ['5', mmmmm]
      - ['6', fffff]
      - ['7', gggggg]
      - ['8', hhhhh]
      - ['9', kkkkkk]

    d2: "{{ dict(l2) }}"
    v1: "{{ l1|map('extract', d2)|list }}"
    l3: "{{ l1|zip(v1) }}"
    l4: "{{ l1|zip(l1|map('extract', dict(l2))|list) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: d2
    - debug:
        var: v1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: l3|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: l4|to_yaml
```

- The filter *to_yaml* can use [*anchor*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#yaml-anchors-and-aliases-sharing-variable-values)

```yaml
 l3|to_yaml: |-
    - ['10', xxxxx]
    - ['2', yyyyy]
    - ['4', zzzzz]
    - ['5', mmmmm]
    - ['6', fffff]
    - &id001 ['7', gggggg]
    - *id001
    - ['8', hhhhh]
    - ['9', kkkkkk]
```

- Use [*community.general.yaml*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/yaml_callback.html#community-general-yaml-callback-yaml-ized-ansible-screen-output) callback.

```bash
shell> ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK
DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK(/scratch/test-061/ansible.cfg) = yaml
```